# php error when I use xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

The following if the error in php error log

> symbol lookup error: /usr/local/php5/extensions/xdebug.so: undefined symbol: php_get_module_initialized

And with this error, I cannot use the debug mode for php with apache. As, if mysql code has error, the brower show a empty page, but not a error page to tell me what is happening.

Anyone saw this error?

Comment: Which version of xdebug are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line in php.ini:

```
zend_extension="/usr/local/php5/extensions/xdebug.so"
```